# render a small texture every frame and then scale it up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

Using OpenGL on iOS, is it possible to update a small texture (by setting each pixel individually) and then scale it up to fill the screen (60 frames per second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update the content of a texture using glTexImage2D.

Untested example:

```
GLubyte data[1024]; // 32x32 (power of two) 
for (int i=0; i<1024; i+=4) {
    // write a red pixel  (RGBA)    
    data[i] = 255;
    data[i+1] = 0;
    data[i+2] = 0;
    data[i+3] = 255;
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, my_texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// then simply render a quad with this texture.
```

Comment: Works once I made it a power of two. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is yes, it is possible. But it might depend on what you need to draw.

Since you don't provide more details I will describe the general approach:

- Bind a texture to a framebuffer ([Here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/chblending.html) is a good explanation with code on how to do that. See *"Example 6.10. Initialize() for Supersampling"* code example)
- Now draw what you need in the same way as you would on the screen (transformations, modelview matrix etc). If you need pixel accuracy (to modify each and every pixel) you might consider using an orthographic projection. If this is possible or not, depends on what you need to draw. All this drawing will be performed on your texture achieving the "update the texture" part.
- Bind the normal framebuffer that you use, to draw on the screen. Draw a rectangle (possibly using orthographic projection again) that uses the texture from the previous step. You can scale this rectangle to fill the screen.

If the above approach would be able to achieve a 60 fps, depends on your target device and the scene you need to render.

Hope that  helps

Comment: I'm less interested in rendering the current scene to a texture. To clarify, I'd like to set each pixel explicitly in a (offscreen?) texture, and then present it fullscreen (scaled up, blurred is ok). Texturing a quad sounds like a reasonable solution for that part. What I'm not clear on, is if it's possible to set individual pixels in a texture directly? Like array access. Or would I render the scene as a series of GL_POINTS in an orth view to achieve the same thing?

Comment: As far as I know, setting the pixels like accesing an array is not possible. `GL_POINTS` could be one way if you can setup your values for the whole texture to all be modified at once. Alternatively you could draw any 2d geometry e.g. if you render a quad (let's say the bottom half of the screen) you could modify a lot of pixels at once. If you describe what you need to draw on that texture perhaps I could provide more help